# Validations not executing in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, validation, oracle-apex

Apex version = 22.0

In my mind I have done everything right, validations are set before processing. The debug mode didn't show anything werid, the item accepts validations and the validation is set after hitting the submit page button. But it only shows the build in validations. The type of validation is an function body returning an error message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk2ev.png

This is the code, I tried to post it as text, but that didnt work for some reason.
Does anybody what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot. If I want to try out your code I have to type it word for word - and just like yourself... I like copying and pasting not typing :)

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough info to give a conclusive answer, so I'd suggest you go through the following:

- "But it only shows the build in validations". I suppose that you mean the validations that are set on the page item as attributes, for example "value required". Note that these validations are executed on the client before the page is submitted to the server. So if you have a combination of these validations and before processing server side validations they will not be executed together. First you'll see the client side validations. When those are fixed and the page is submitted again, the server side validations will fire. For better user experience, you could use only server side validations (but then the label will not show as "required").
- Do a test: remove all other validations, except for this particular one and submit the page. Does it fire correctly ? If no, what do do you see in debug (Please be more clear than "the debug didn't show anything weird"... what does that mean ??)
- I did a quick test myself. This worked perfectly:

[image]

Comment: Right; my first thought was that you (Bjarne) should first make sure that all errors Apex reports ("built in", as you said) are fixed. Then see whether your own validation works as expected. BTW, empty string (in Oracle) is equal to NULL so no need to check both (I'd check for NULL).

Comment: Thank you very much, I used your trick of removing all the validations (in this case value required) and it worked. I'm sorry that the information wasnt that clear, I'm still very bad at using this application. I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: In that case, @Bjarne, consider accepting Koen's answer.